# MySQL ORDER BY приближенное значение

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток!
Сразу приведу пример чтобы было понятно.
На сайте стандартный поиск сортирует по title (названию новости).
У нас есть например 2 новости "**семь**" и "**восемь**"
и если ввести "**семь**" то выведет в первую очередь "**восемь**", т.к. у нас сортировка по алфавиту.
Как написать поиск более точный?
**PHP**

Comment: попробуйте **пробел+семь**

Comment: спасибо за отклик. а самом запросе имеете ввиду? ORDER BY title

Comment: вам нужно что бы поиск выдавал новостей сначала начинаюшие с "семь" а потом другие где есть слово "семь" так?

Comment: верно, главное чтобы было сначала семь

Comment: По идее это не так легко сделать. Т.е. Вы либо потеряете возможность искать по вхождению в середине текста (что скорее всего неприемлемо), либо Вам придется придумывать какой-то хотя бы простейший алгоритм определения релевантности результатов поиска и далее ранжировать по нему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если конкретно надо вот прям сначала те которые начинаются, а потом которые только содержат, то

```
WHERE title LIKE 'семь%' ORDER BY title UNION SELECT ... 
WHERE title LIKE '%семь%' ORDER BY title
```

Но вообще то что тебе нужно называется **полнотекстовый поиск**.

Comment: уже ищет точнее. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
SELECT title,  CONCAT(' ', title) as title_ext
FROM table
WHERE title like '%семь%'
ORDER BY CONCAT(' ', title)
```